# Fail to use spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I want to execute an spark project to connect to cassandra by using **spark-cassandra-connector** as following:

version:

- Cassandra:2.1.2
- CassandraDriver:2.1.3
- Spark: 1.1.0

**build.sbt**

```
name := "sparktest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.1.0" withSources() withJavadoc()
```

**sparkCassandra.scala**

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark._

object SparkTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
    val sc = new SparkContext("spark://master:7077", "test", conf)

    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "users")
    println(rdd.count) 
  }
}
```

But when I execute this project by

```
spark-submit --class "SparkTest"  target/scala-2.10/sparktest_2.10-1.0.jar
```

It occurs error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9160
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.createThriftClient(CassandraConnector.scala:132)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.createThriftClient(CassandraConnector.scala:138)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withCassandraClientDo(CassandraConnector.scala:144)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraRDDPartitioner.partitions(CassandraRDDPartitioner.scala:158)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.getPartitions(CassandraRDD.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1135)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:904)
        at SparkTest$.main(sparkcassandra.scala:14)
        at SparkTest.main(sparkcassandra.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TFramedTransportFactory.openTransport(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport;
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createThriftClient(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:47)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.createThriftClient(CassandraConnector.scala:127)
        ... 19 more
```

I find that if I type wrong Table name, it will say "Table not Found"
It seems that the connection is successful.

But it will cause the above error when I use the cassandra table rdd.
I can't figure out what reason of this error,if there anyone could help me?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: just try `telnet 127.0.0.1 9160` -> do you get a connection?

Comment: it shows:  "  Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
"

Comment: if start_rpc: false in yaml file then make it true

Answer (score 0):

I think you cassandra is not running on port 9160.Can you verify it in cassandra.yaml file and also verify using telnet 127.0.0.1 9160 and see it it can telnet to this port.

Comment: it shows: "Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'. "

Comment: But I'm confused by "  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TFramedTransportFactory.openTransport(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport; "

Comment: Is this error also means that my cassandra port doesn't work?

Comment: Can you once confirm in cassandra.yaml for the port also can you try once changing the default cassandra port  - @Jhong-YiChen

Comment: I've check the port and could connect by "telnet" without error. But it still have the same error... Thanks for reply with patient~!  @Sachin Janani

Comment: Can you please your post your cassandra.yaml file @Jhong-Yi Chen

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the save problem before.
This error is caused by version mismatch between Cassandra driver and host.
So check if you have included lower version of Cassandra driver in your spark-application-jar. 
In this case you should use Cassandra driver 2.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem with two corrections:

1. Use localhost instead of IP.
2. `val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`

there is no other changes in further steps.
Hope it will work for you too.